# Increment nested array value +1 else set to 1

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm pulling a list of products from a mysql table and I'm adding up the total product type count per location within a php array. I know I could do this through mysql but Its a little more complicated than that so lets say a php array is my only option!

The mysql query will be set to the array $products is setup like this:

```
Index         product_type       location
0          Chevy              South Bend
1          Ford               Aurora
2          Chevy              South Bend
3          Chevy              Aurora
```

I then have the following code to setup the array I will use for display:

```
$myProducts = array();
if(is_array($products){
    foreach($products as $product){
      if(isset($myProducts['location']['product_type'])){
           $myProducts['location']['product_type'] ++;
      }else{
           $myProducts['location']['product_type'] = 1;
      }
    }
}
```

This method works in terms of display but I get hammered with the errors like the following:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: South Bend
```

I've tried doing the following with the same results in warnings.

```
if(is_array($myProducts['location']) && isset($myProducts['location']['product_type'])){

}
```

Is there a method where I don't need to do nested if statements to check if location is an array and then within that if statement check to see if product type is set for that location?

Comment: can you show the desired output?

Comment: what you exactly want to count? as per your code its count the number of `$products`. it can be done by using `count($products)`? can you explain what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

add after the first line of the foreach, to create the array and stop the notices

```
if(!isset($myProducts['location']['product_type'])){$myProducts['location']['product_type']=0}
```

Comment: It is the isset($myProducts['location']['product_type']) thats causing the warning for location not being a defined index. I wasn't sure if there was some suave way checking if a nested array isset without having to check the parents

Comment: i know, i check if its not set, and only then create it